# AWS Gateway Output Passthrough enalbled but Response headers not forwarded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've got an AWS API Gateway with a resource (contacts) with an OPTIONS method (with CORS enabled) and a POST method which just add some headers during Integration Request before forwarding it to an http endpoint.

Integration Request is working fine but the output response doesn't contain original endpoint response headers.

When i test the endpoint from the aws console i can see the original response headers but in the final ouput i get only:

```
{"X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

Same result with Postman and my web browsers.

Righ now any response from the original endpoint is mapped to an HTTP 200 status in the response method. I will later correctly map a success to a 201, but i want first understand why i can't forward the headers correctly (the body response is correct)

Maybe i'm missing something in the Integration or Method response, but i can't see what...

Comment: Did you declare the desired headers in the integration response, and then map them in the method response? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-response-parameters

Comment: I've done that, but i was thinking it was a fix (in my case), not the regular way to forward all headers. 
Is there a way to tell aws api gateway i want all the original response headers mapped to there original values? 

If the response to my question is obvious, i'm really sorry to ask, but i'm having a hard time navigating in the whole aws documentation ;)